# Freelancer launched an app, explaining to others I'm just myself (can't afford to hire)

Tags: information-technology

This happens to me consistently. [Launched an app](https://twitter.com/drawmaticar) last month and I now have daily emails of studios asking me to hire them.

Many of them don't have anything close in portfolio [experience](https://permute.xyz/timeline) to what I have. Some of them want to charge outrageously cheap rates (but only for volume) - but being a lean one person startup, tbh, I can't really afford them.

How do you explain to others (especially studios) that despite the success of said app, you're just a one person studio (also, financial success is not quite there yet)... you can't really afford to hire them, and might sometimes appreciate it if they share jobs. (Actually, generally, I am very picky on what I take these days, so it is also unlikely that I would be interested in their job.)

Comment: Why close? This is a freelancing problem when you can do everything to try launching an product/app yourself but don't exactly have the capital to do beyond

Comment: Hasn't it worked explaining you're just yourself? Or are you looking to completely avoid these conversations?

Comment: So I've had these conversations. The most common case is it's met with misunderstanding. It ranges from drama to next week, same spam.

Comment: There's just no way someone these studios are *advertising to* is going to convince them to essentially reverse the relationship they are trying to establish. They want your money.... they aren't going to be interested in giving *you* money. This is *especially* true for marketers using "spam" as a tactic.

Comment: This is what https://www.spamcop.net/ is for.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, I get the feeling you explain too much. The longer dialog you accept having, the more they get the feeling you could be convinced.

A simple, short and firm **I'm not interested in collaborating with others** should do.

Comment: Upvoted both current answers, but I prefer the succinctness of this one.

Answer (score 2):

I've built a few websites that have the same problem, but only occasional spam from a company wanting to "fix errors", "increase SEO", or something like that.

The way I respond to those contacts is silence. If it's an email or text, I delete it with no response. If it's a robocall, I hang up, or I punch random numbers to confuse their system then hang up. If it's an actual piece of mail, it goes in the "secure destruction" pile.

If it's a phone call, I simply state I'm not interested. Like morsor said, don't explain anything, and keep it short and simple. A sales person knows that if they keep you talking, you're likely to cave and buy. It's hard for them to sell something if all they hear is a dial tone. Although, don't be rude unless they just can't take "no" for an answer.